# Cakephp subdomain in subdirectory not loading static files

Tags: cakephp, subdomain, subdirectory

I have CakePHP in a subfolder `public_html/cakedir`, the folder being accessed from `http://cakedir.mydomain.com`. Everything seems to be working so far except that the static files are not being found, giving me 404 on the css files.

I'm unable to find anything useful on this issue, though it seems like something straightforward, so perhaps I'm just searching the wrong terms.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Apache? if so this sounds more like a configuration problem. What does your config look like? htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the `.htaccess` file in webroot. Add `RewriteBase /cakedir/app/webroot/` after `RewriteEngine On` and it'll work!